# How to find how many times a particular ip is pinged to the url?

Tags: python, ip-address

I have a python script which extracts unique IP addresses from a log file and displays their count of how many times those IPs are pinged the code is as follows.

```
import sys

def extract_ip(line):
    return line.split()[0]

def increase_count(ip_dict, ip_addr):
    if ip_addr in ip_dict:
       ip_dict[ip_addr] += 1
    else:
       ip_dict[ip_addr] = 1

def read_ips(infilename):
    res_dict = {}
    log_file = file(infilename)
    for line in log_file:
        if line.isspace():
           continue
        ip_addr = extract_ip(line)
        increase_count(res_dict, ip_addr)
    return res_dict

def write_ips(outfilename, ip_dict):
    out_file = file(outfilename, "w")
    for ip_addr, count in ip_dict.iteritems():
        out_file.write("%5d\t%s\n" % (count, ip_addr))
    out_file.close()

def parse_cmd_line_args():
    if len(sys.argv)!=3:
       print("Usage: %s [infilename] [outfilename]" % sys.argv[0])
       sys.exit(1)
    return sys.argv[1], sys.argv[2]

def main():
    infilename, outfilename = parse_cmd_line_args()
    ip_dict = read_ips(infilename)
    write_ips(outfilename, ip_dict)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

The log file is in the following format with 2L lines. These are the first 30 lines of the log file

```
220.227.40.118 - - [06/Mar/2012:00:00:00 -0800] "GET /mysidebars/newtab.html HTTP/1.1" 404 0 - -
220.227.40.118 - - [06/Mar/2012:00:00:00 -0800] "GET /hrefadd.xml HTTP/1.1" 204 214 - -
59.95.13.217 - - [06/Mar/2012:00:00:00 -0800] "GET /dbupdates2.xml HTTP/1.1" 404 0 - -
111.92.9.222 - - [06/Mar/2012:00:00:00 -0800] "GET /mysidebars/newtab.html HTTP/1.1" 404 0 - -
120.56.236.46 - - [06/Mar/2012:00:00:00 -0800] "GET /hrefadd.xml HTTP/1.1" 204 214 - -
49.138.106.21 - - [06/Mar/2012:00:00:00 -0800] "GET /add.txt HTTP/1.1" 204 214 - -
117.195.185.130 - - [06/Mar/2012:00:00:00 -0800] "GET /mysidebars/newtab.html HTTP/1.1" 404 0 - -
122.160.166.220 - - [06/Mar/2012:00:00:00 -0800] "GET /mysidebars/newtab.html HTTP/1.1" 404 0 - -
117.214.20.28 - - [06/Mar/2012:00:00:00 -0800] "GET /welcome.html HTTP/1.1" 204 212 - -
117.18.231.5 - - [06/Mar/2012:00:00:00 -0800] "GET /mysidebars/newtab.html HTTP/1.1" 404 0 - -
117.18.231.5 - - [06/Mar/2012:00:00:00 -0800] "GET /mysidebars/newtab.html HTTP/1.1" 404 0 - -
122.169.136.211 - - [06/Mar/2012:00:00:00 -0800] "GET /mysidebars/newtab.html HTTP/1.1" 404 0 - -
203.217.145.10 - - [06/Mar/2012:00:00:00 -0800] "GET /mysidebars/newtab.html HTTP/1.1" 404 0 - -
117.18.231.5 - - [06/Mar/2012:00:00:00 -0800] "GET /hrefadd.xml HTTP/1.1" 204 214 - -
59.95.13.217 - - [06/Mar/2012:00:00:00 -0800] "GET /dbupdates2.xml HTTP/1.1" 404 0 - -
203.217.145.10 - - [06/Mar/2012:00:00:00 -0800] "GET /mysidebars/newtab.html HTTP/1.1" 404 0 - -
117.206.70.4 - - [06/Mar/2012:00:00:00 -0800] "GET /mysidebars/newtab.html HTTP/1.1" 404 0 - -
117.214.20.28 - - [06/Mar/2012:00:00:00 -0800] "GET /css/epic.css HTTP/1.1" 204 214 "http://www.epicbrowser.com/welcome.html" -
117.206.70.4 - - [06/Mar/2012:00:00:00 -0800] "GET /add.txt HTTP/1.1" 204 214 - -
117.206.70.4 - - [06/Mar/2012:00:00:00 -0800] "GET /hrefadd.xml HTTP/1.1" 204 214 - -
118.97.38.130 - - [06/Mar/2012:00:00:00 -0800] "GET /mysidebars/newtab.html HTTP/1.1" 404 0 - -
117.214.20.28 - - [06/Mar/2012:00:00:00 -0800] "GET /js/flash_detect_min.js HTTP/1.1" 304 0 "http://www.epicbrowser.com/welcome.html" -
117.214.20.28 - - [06/Mar/2012:00:00:00 -0800] "GET /images/home-page-bottom.jpg HTTP/1.1" 304 0 "http://www.epicbrowser.com/welcome.html" -
117.214.20.28 - - [06/Mar/2012:00:00:00 -0800] "GET /images/Facebook_Like.png HTTP/1.1" 204 214 "http://www.epicbrowser.com/welcome.html" -
117.214.20.28 - - [06/Mar/2012:00:00:00 -0800] "GET /images/Twitter_Follow.png HTTP/1.1" 204 214 "http://www.epicbrowser.com/welcome.html" -
117.214.20.28 - - [06/Mar/2012:00:00:00 -0800] "GET /images/home-page-top.jpg HTTP/1.1" 304 0 "http://www.epicbrowser.com/welcome.html" -
49.138.106.21 - - [06/Mar/2012:00:00:01 -0800] "GET /dbupdates2.xml HTTP/1.1" 404 0 - -
117.18.231.5 - - [06/Mar/2012:00:00:01 -0800] "GET /mysidebars/newtab.html HTTP/1.1" 404 0 - -
117.18.231.5 - - [06/Mar/2012:00:00:01 -0800] "GET /hrefadd.xml HTTP/1.1" 204 214 - -
120.61.182.186 - - [06/Mar/2012:00:00:01 -0800] "GET /mysidebars/newtab.html HTTP/1.1" 404 0 - -
```

the output of the file is in the following format

```
    Number of Times      IPS
     158            111.92.9.222
     11             58.97.187.231
     30             212.57.209.41
     5              119.235.51.66
     3              122.168.134.106
     5              180.234.220.75
     13             115.252.223.243
```

Here the ip 111.92.9.222 - - [06/Mar/2012:00:00:00 -0800] "GET /mysidebars/newtab.html HTTP/1.1" 404 0 - - is pinged into epic 158 times totally.

Now i want to add a functionality to the code so that if i pass a particular URL, it should return how many times the URL was accessed by which IP addresses(IP address either from log file or from output file).

E.g. if I pass the url as input: http://www.epicbrowser.com/hrefadd.xml

the output should be in the following format

```
     10.10.128.134        4
     10.134.222.232       6
```

Comment: You may want to consider using a database instead of files for this

Comment: @gnibbler, i was given the task to write a python file for the requirement.

Comment: Python comes with sqlite. Why not use that to store the data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume your requirement that you want only IPs of one given URL is true.  In this case you just have to add an additional filter to the program which filters out the unwanted lines. The structure of the program can be unchanged.

Because the log files do not know anything about hosts, you have to specify only the path part of the URL as the third parameter; example: "/hrefadd.xml"

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# 
# Counts the IP addresses of a log file.
# 
# Assumption: the IP address is logged in the first column.
# Example line: 117.195.185.130 - - [06/Mar/2012:00:00:00 -0800] \
#    "GET /mysidebars/newtab.html HTTP/1.1" 404 0 - -
#

import sys

def urlcheck(line, url):
    '''Checks if the url is part of the log line.'''
    lsplit = line.split()
    if len(lsplit)<7:
        return False
    return url==lsplit[6]

def extract_ip(line):
    '''Extracts the IP address from the line.
       Currently it is assumed, that the IP address is logged in
       the first column and the columns are space separated.'''
    return line.split()[0]

def increase_count(ip_dict, ip_addr):
    '''Increases the count of the IP address.
       If an IP address is not in the given dictionary,
       it is initially created and the count is set to 1.'''
    if ip_addr in ip_dict:
        ip_dict[ip_addr] += 1
    else:
        ip_dict[ip_addr] = 1

def read_ips(infilename, url):
    '''Read the IP addresses from the file and store (count)
       them in a dictionary - returns the dictionary.'''
    res_dict = {}
    log_file = file(infilename)
    for line in log_file:
        if line.isspace():
            continue
        if not urlcheck(line, url):
            continue
        ip_addr = extract_ip(line)
        increase_count(res_dict, ip_addr)
    return res_dict

def write_ips(outfilename, ip_dict):
    '''Write out the count and the IP addresses.'''
    out_file = file(outfilename, "w")
    for ip_addr, count in ip_dict.iteritems():
        out_file.write("%s\t%5d\n" % (ip_addr, count))
    out_file.close()

def parse_cmd_line_args():
    '''Return the in and out file name.
       If there are more or less than two parameters,
       an error is logged in the program is exited.'''
    if len(sys.argv)!=4:
        print("Usage: %s [infilename] [outfilename] [url]" % sys.argv[0])
        sys.exit(1)
    return sys.argv[1], sys.argv[2], sys.argv[3]

def main():
    infilename, outfilename, url = parse_cmd_line_args()
    ip_dict = read_ips(infilename, url)
    write_ips(outfilename, ip_dict)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

IMHO it would be helpful if also the original [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9630096/how-to-print-the-output-returned-from-a-function-in-new-lines-using-python/9630921#9630921) was referenced.

IMHO you should leave the comments in place.

Comment: my actual log file format is, 117.214.20.28 - - [06/Mar/2012:00:00:00 -0800] "GET /images/home-page-bottom.jpg HTTP/1.1" 304 0 "http://www.epicbrowser.com/welcome.html" - ... for some file the last url is not present.

Comment: The last url in your comment example is the referer (see [link](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/logs.html) ).  As far a I understood, you want to check the url itself and not the referer; in the url there is no host at all. If this is the case, the program should work.

Comment: i want to modify the code such a way that if i pass a date instead of url, i want all the ips pinged on that particular date. For example if the date is 06/Mar/2012, i want all the ips pinged on that date. I tried and modified the code on my own, but its not working. i need ur help. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your problem cries out for the use of a relational database.

Using a database will let you construct queries like "how many hits did I get from each URL?" as SQL queries like `SELECT ip, COUNT(ip) as hits FROM requests GROUP BY ip`. The database will then take care of looping through the data and counting things.

Complete solution using an in-memory SQLite database given below. I have tested this and it works. 'logfile.txt' should be a file of precisely the format you gave in your example above.

Edit: Revised to work with imprecisely specified data format - the only requirements now are that each row must consist of at least seven whitespace-separated fields, of which the first field must be an IP in dotted quad format, and the seventh field must be a path starting with '/'.

(Note the use of defensive programming techniques - check that the data you're getting looks the way you expect it to look, and raise an error if the data is malformed. This prevents the bad data from causing your entire program to blow up later.)

```
import os, sqlite3, re

fh = open('logfile.txt','r')

db = sqlite3.connect(':memory:') #create temporary SQLite database in memory

db.execute("""
CREATE TABLE requests (
    ip TEXT,
    url TEXT
)
""")

for line in fh:
    line_split = line.split()
    if len(line_split) < 7:
        raise ValueError ("Not enough fields - need at least seven.")

    ip = line_split[0]
    url = line_split[6]

    # Check that the 'ip' variable really contains four sets of number separated by dots.
    if (re.match(r'\d+\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+', ip) == None):
        errmsg = "The value %s found in the first column was not an IP address." % ip
        raise ValueError (errmsg)

    # check that the 'url' variable contains a string starting with /
    if (url.startswith("/") == False):
        errmsg = "The value %s found in the 7th column was not a path beginning with /" % url
        raise ValueError ( errmsg )


    #if len(line_split) != 12:
    #    print (line_split)
    #    raise ValueError("Malformatted line - must have 10 fields")
    db.execute("INSERT INTO requests VALUES (?,?)",(ip,url) )

db.commit() #save data

# print what's in the database
print("\nData in the database\n")
results = db.execute("SELECT * FROM requests")
for row in results:
    print row

# Count hits from each IP
print ("\nNumber of hits from each IP\n")
results = db.execute("""
SELECT ip, COUNT(ip) AS hits
FROM requests
GROUP BY ip""")
for row in results:
    print(row)

# Count hits from each IP for the particular URL '/mysidebars/newtab.html'
print("\nNumber of hits from each IP for url %s" % url)
target_url = '/mysidebars/newtab.html'
results = db.execute("""
SELECT ip, COUNT(ip) AS hits
FROM requests
WHERE url=?
GROUP BY ip
""", [target_url])
for row in results:
    print(row)
```

The output is:

```
Data in the database

(u'220.227.40.118', u'/mysidebars/newtab.html')
(u'220.227.40.118', u'/hrefadd.xml')
(u'59.95.13.217', u'/dbupdates2.xml')
(u'111.92.9.222', u'/mysidebars/newtab.html')
(u'120.56.236.46', u'/hrefadd.xml')
(u'49.138.106.21', u'/add.txt')
(u'117.195.185.130', u'/mysidebars/newtab.html')
(u'122.160.166.220', u'/mysidebars/newtab.html')
(u'117.214.20.28', u'/welcome.html')
(u'117.18.231.5', u'/mysidebars/newtab.html')
(u'117.18.231.5', u'/mysidebars/newtab.html')
(u'122.169.136.211', u'/mysidebars/newtab.html')
(u'203.217.145.10', u'/mysidebars/newtab.html')
(u'117.18.231.5', u'/hrefadd.xml')
(u'59.95.13.217', u'/dbupdates2.xml')
(u'203.217.145.10', u'/mysidebars/newtab.html')
(u'117.206.70.4', u'/mysidebars/newtab.html')
(u'117.214.20.28', u'/css/epic.css')
(u'117.206.70.4', u'/add.txt')
(u'117.206.70.4', u'/hrefadd.xml')
(u'118.97.38.130', u'/mysidebars/newtab.html')
(u'117.214.20.28', u'/js/flash_detect_min.js')
(u'117.214.20.28', u'/images/home-page-bottom.jpg')
(u'117.214.20.28', u'/images/Facebook_Like.png')
(u'117.214.20.28', u'/images/Twitter_Follow.png')
(u'117.214.20.28', u'/images/home-page-top.jpg')
(u'49.138.106.21', u'/dbupdates2.xml')
(u'117.18.231.5', u'/mysidebars/newtab.html')
(u'117.18.231.5', u'/hrefadd.xml')
(u'120.61.182.186', u'/mysidebars/newtab.html')

Number of hits from each IP

(u'111.92.9.222', 1)
(u'117.18.231.5', 5)
(u'117.195.185.130', 1)
(u'117.206.70.4', 3)
(u'117.214.20.28', 7)
(u'118.97.38.130', 1)
(u'120.56.236.46', 1)
(u'120.61.182.186', 1)
(u'122.160.166.220', 1)
(u'122.169.136.211', 1)
(u'203.217.145.10', 2)
(u'220.227.40.118', 2)
(u'49.138.106.21', 2)
(u'59.95.13.217', 2)

Number of hits from each IP for url /mysidebars/newtab.html
(u'111.92.9.222', 1)
(u'117.18.231.5', 3)
(u'117.195.185.130', 1)
(u'117.206.70.4', 1)
(u'118.97.38.130', 1)
(u'120.61.182.186', 1)
(u'122.160.166.220', 1)
(u'122.169.136.211', 1)
(u'203.217.145.10', 2)
(u'220.227.40.118', 1)
```

---

**Sidenote:** Your existing code is not a good solution to your problem (SQL is a much better way of dealing with "tabular" data.) But if you ever need to count occurrences of a repeated value for another purpose, [collections.Counter from the standard library](http://docs.python.org/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) is easier to use and faster than your `increase_count()` function.

Comment: when i run your code, i get the following ValueError message (which u have given in the code)

           i have edited the input log file i have given as example, i have included first 30 lines of the log file for ur reference.


['66.249.68.193', '-', '-', '[06/Mar/2012:00:00:08', '-0800]', '"GET', '/wallpap
er/1872/skins.html', 'HTTP/1.1"', '200', '2460', '-', '"http://www.google.com/bo
t.html"', '-']
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "newcode.py", line 31, in <module>
    raise ValueError("Malformatted line - must have 10 fields")
ValueError: Malformatted line - must have 10 fields

Comment: The `ValueError` exception is thrown because your logfile.txt contains an extra field (`google.com/bot.html`) that wasn't part of the example you originally gave. The code above expects exactly 12 space-separated fields, no more, no less, and I inserted an error check (`if len(split_line) != 12:`) to make sure this was the case. The row in your logfile that triggered the error has 13 fields.

Comment: Also, I made a typo - the error message should read "must have **12** fields."

Comment: @Raju.allen : I have revised my example code to work with your example data provided above. Note that if you have control over the format of the logfile, you should really make it easier to parse (see: `csv` format with comma separators.)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using a database (which might be a better solution in the long run) you can use a dictionary of dictionaries.

```
urls = {}

def increase_path_count(dict, path, ip_addr):
    if path not in dict:
        dict[path] = {}
   increase_count(dict[path], ip_addr)
```

**Edit**

You have to parse the actual contents of the logfile to get the path. This can be done with the [regular expression](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html) module. A good regular expression to start with might be this:

```
'GET (?P<path>/[\w.]+)'
```

Since you only have the paths in the logfile, you need to extract the path from the URL in the command line argument. This can be done with the [urlparse](http://docs.python.org/library/urlparse.html) module.

**Edit 2**

```
import re

# ....

def read_ips_and_paths(infilename, url):
    '''Read the IP addresses and paths from the file and store (count)
       them in a dictionary - returns the dictionary.'''
    res_dict = {}
    log_file = file(infilename)
    for line in log_file:
        if line.isspace():
            continue

        # Get the ip address for the log entry
        ip_addr = extract_ip(line)

        # Get the path from the log entry
        match = re.search('GET (?P<path>/[\w.]+)', line);
        path = match.group('path')

        increase_path_count(res_dict, path, ip_addr)

    return res_dict
```

Now when you want to get all IP addresses and counts for a specific path, you use `urlparse` to get the path part of the URL supplied from the command line:

```
from urlparse import urlparse

# ....

url_path = urlparse(complete_url).path
```

Not you use the path to print the requested data:

```
for i in url_dict[url_path].items():
    print "ip address: %r - %d" % (i[0], i[1])
```

Comment: thanks for your help. but how can i pass the url and how to use that url in the code. if i include your code and run my file it gives me the same output file.

Comment: Sorry sir i'm new to python. I dono how to parse regular expression.