# How to find how many ips are pinged on a particular date?

Tags: python, python-2.x

I have a python file, i pass the log file and a url to the code. The output file contains how many times the URL was accessed by which IP addresses.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# 
# Counts the IP addresses of a log file.
# 
# Assumption: the IP address is logged in the first column.
# Example line: 117.195.185.130 - - [06/Mar/2012:00:00:00 -0800] \
#    "GET /mysidebars/newtab.html HTTP/1.1" 404 0 - -
#

import sys

def urlcheck(line, url):
    '''Checks if the url is part of the log line.'''
    lsplit = line.split()
    if len(lsplit)<7:
        return False
    return url==lsplit[6]

def extract_ip(line):
    '''Extracts the IP address from the line.
       Currently it is assumed, that the IP address is logged in
       the first column and the columns are space separated.'''
    return line.split()[0]

def increase_count(ip_dict, ip_addr):
    '''Increases the count of the IP address.
       If an IP address is not in the given dictionary,
       it is initially created and the count is set to 1.'''
    if ip_addr in ip_dict:
        ip_dict[ip_addr] += 1
    else:
        ip_dict[ip_addr] = 1

def read_ips(infilename, url):
    '''Read the IP addresses from the file and store (count)
       them in a dictionary - returns the dictionary.'''
    res_dict = {}
    log_file = file(infilename)
    for line in log_file:
        if line.isspace():
            continue
        if not urlcheck(line, url):
            continue
        ip_addr = extract_ip(line)
        increase_count(res_dict, ip_addr)
    return res_dict

def write_ips(outfilename, ip_dict):
    '''Write out the count and the IP addresses.'''
    out_file = file(outfilename, "w")
    for ip_addr, count in ip_dict.iteritems():
        out_file.write("%s\t%5d\n" % (ip_addr, count))
    out_file.close()

def parse_cmd_line_args():
    '''Return the in and out file name.
       If there are more or less than two parameters,
       an error is logged in the program is exited.'''
    if len(sys.argv)!=4:
        print("Usage: %s [infilename] [outfilename] [url]" % sys.argv[0])
        sys.exit(1)
    return sys.argv[1], sys.argv[2], sys.argv[3]

def main():
    infilename, outfilename, url = parse_cmd_line_args()
    ip_dict = read_ips(infilename, url)
    write_ips(outfilename, ip_dict)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

now i want to modify the code in such a way that, if i pass a date instead of url, the output file should contain all ips which are pinged on that particular date.

the log file format is as follows.

```
220.227.40.118 - - [06/Mar/2012:00:00:00 -0800] "GET /mysidebars/newtab.html HTTP/1.1" 404 0 - -
220.227.40.118 - - [06/Mar/2012:00:00:00 -0800] "GET /hrefadd.xml HTTP/1.1" 204 214 - -
59.95.13.217 - - [06/Mar/2012:00:00:00 -0800] "GET /dbupdates2.xml HTTP/1.1" 404 0 - -
111.92.9.222 - - [06/Mar/2012:00:00:00 -0800] "GET /mysidebars/newtab.html HTTP/1.1" 404 0 - -
120.56.236.46 - - [06/Mar/2012:00:00:00 -0800] "GET /hrefadd.xml HTTP/1.1" 204 214 - -
49.138.106.21 - - [06/Mar/2012:00:00:00 -0800] "GET /add.txt HTTP/1.1" 204 214 - -
117.195.185.130 - - [06/Mar/2012:00:00:00 -0800] "GET /mysidebars/newtab.html HTTP/1.1" 404 0 - -
122.160.166.220 - - [06/Mar/2012:00:00:00 -0800] "GET /mysidebars/newtab.html HTTP/1.1" 404 0 - -
117.214.20.28 - - [06/Mar/2012:00:00:00 -0800] "GET /welcome.html HTTP/1.1" 204 212 - -
117.18.231.5 - - [06/Mar/2012:00:00:00 -0800] "GET /mysidebars/newtab.html HTTP/1.1" 404 0 - -
117.18.231.5 - - [06/Mar/2012:00:00:00 -0800] "GET /mysidebars/newtab.html HTTP/1.1" 404 0 - -
122.169.136.211 - - [06/Mar/2012:00:00:00 -0800] "GET /mysidebars/newtab.html HTTP/1.1" 404 0 - -
203.217.145.10 - - [06/Mar/2012:00:00:00 -0800] "GET /mysidebars/newtab.html HTTP/1.1" 404 0 - -
117.18.231.5 - - [06/Mar/2012:00:00:00 -0800] "GET /hrefadd.xml HTTP/1.1" 204 214 - -
59.95.13.217 - - [06/Mar/2012:00:00:00 -0800] "GET /dbupdates2.xml HTTP/1.1" 404 0 - -
203.217.145.10 - - [06/Mar/2012:00:00:00 -0800] "GET /mysidebars/newtab.html HTTP/1.1" 404 0 - -
117.206.70.4 - - [06/Mar/2012:00:00:00 -0800] "GET /mysidebars/newtab.html HTTP/1.1" 404 0 - -
117.214.20.28 - - [06/Mar/2012:00:00:00 -0800] "GET /css/epic.css HTTP/1.1" 204 214 "http://www.epicbrowser.com/welcome.html" -
117.206.70.4 - - [06/Mar/2012:00:00:00 -0800] "GET /add.txt HTTP/1.1" 204 214 - -
117.206.70.4 - - [06/Mar/2012:00:00:00 -0800] "GET /hrefadd.xml HTTP/1.1" 204 214 - -
118.97.38.130 - - [06/Mar/2012:00:00:00 -0800] "GET /mysidebars/newtab.html HTTP/1.1" 404 0 - -
117.214.20.28 - - [06/Mar/2012:00:00:00 -0800] "GET /js/flash_detect_min.js HTTP/1.1" 304 0 "http://www.epicbrowser.com/welcome.html" -
117.214.20.28 - - [06/Mar/2012:00:00:00 -0800] "GET /images/home-page-bottom.jpg HTTP/1.1" 304 0 "http://www.epicbrowser.com/welcome.html" -
117.214.20.28 - - [06/Mar/2012:00:00:00 -0800] "GET /images/Facebook_Like.png HTTP/1.1" 204 214 "http://www.epicbrowser.com/welcome.html" -
117.214.20.28 - - [06/Mar/2012:00:00:00 -0800] "GET /images/Twitter_Follow.png HTTP/1.1" 204 214 "http://www.epicbrowser.com/welcome.html" -
117.214.20.28 - - [06/Mar/2012:00:00:00 -0800] "GET /images/home-page-top.jpg HTTP/1.1" 304 0 "http://www.epicbrowser.com/welcome.html" -
49.138.106.21 - - [06/Mar/2012:00:00:01 -0800] "GET /dbupdates2.xml HTTP/1.1" 404 0 - -
117.18.231.5 - - [06/Mar/2012:00:00:01 -0800] "GET /mysidebars/newtab.html HTTP/1.1" 404 0 - -
117.18.231.5 - - [06/Mar/2012:00:00:01 -0800] "GET /hrefadd.xml HTTP/1.1" 204 214 - -
120.61.182.186 - - [06/Mar/2012:00:00:01 -0800] "GET /mysidebars/newtab.html HTTP/1.1" 404 0 - -
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to find how many times a particular ip is pinged to the url?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9678609/how-to-find-how-many-times-a-particular-ip-is-pinged-to-the-url)

Comment: Please stop using stackoverflow to write your entire script for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What's wrong with grep, cut, sort and uniq?

```
grep "\[07/Mar/2012" logfile.txt | cut -d " " -f 1 | sort | uniq
```